# I2C not detecting BME280 (the I2C only version) when display is connected to SPI

Tags: gpio, pi-4, i2c, spi

I have bought an ePaper display and an BME280 sensor. The ePaper display itself is successfully powered via SPI (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/4.2inch_e-Paper_Module_(B)) and the BME280 should be powered via I2C.

The problem here is that the BME280 sensor (I already tried several) is not detected via I2C.

Sensor is connected as follows:

```
VIN: Pin 1 (3,3)
GND: Pin 9 (GND)
SCL: Pin 5 (GPIO 3)
SDA: Pin 3 (GPIO 2)
```

I2C is enabled in the raspberry pi 4.

Under /etc/modules it is listed:

```
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2835
```

`ls /dev/i2c*` lists me:

```
/dev/i2c-1
```

`lsmod | grep i2c` lists me:

```
i2c_bcm2835            16384  0
i2c_dev                20480  0
```

And finally the output of `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

As far as I know there is nothing else to do for reading this sensor. So what could be my problem here? Could it be that the Pi could not power both devices? A point against could be that the display itself is not running at the moment (no script for it runs).

I am using a raspberry pi 4 with current raspbian buster lite.

Here is how I have it put together:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

For Better resolution:
(https://ibb.co/7jby0Hs)!
(https://ibb.co/zVqD75M)!

Comment: Is this BME280 one that comes on a breakout board or just the plain chip?

Comment: I have these:

https://www.amazon.de/AZDelivery-GY-BME280-Barometrischer-Temperatur-Luftfeuchtigkeit/dp/B07FS95JXT/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=bme280&qid=1613721515&sr=8-5

Comment: I'd forgot to say that the raspi cam v1 is attached to the pi too

Comment: Hmm... there's not much you can mess up with this chip. Some chips that have both SPI and I2c support sometimes act out if the unused pins are floating, but this one does not _have_ any extra connections.

Comment: We need a clear photo showing the connections between Pi and module.

Comment: okay here they are. Hopefully it will help :-)

Comment: Looks all good to me. Do you have any other I2C devices to play with?

Comment: I have not soldered anything atm. I want to do this when everything works fine

Comment: This Sensor comes with 4 pin plug. I have pushed it through the holes of the PCB and attached the gpio females on it

Comment: You need to solder the pins to the module.  Just pushing through does not make a connection.

Comment: @joan at another pi 3 the Connection is working without soldering

Comment: This happens.  And the next time it's joggled it may stop or start working.  Only you can judge if that is reliable enough for your application.